# js: does user selection traverse multiple elements

Tags: javascript, dom

Going nuts...

I want to know if the user has selected one or more elements. However, these elements should only include actual elements with text.

I tried comparing the selection anchorNode (start) to the selection focusNode (end) and seeing whether they were the same. This, however, gives different results in different browsers, and different results depending on how the text was selected. This needs to work in at least IE (> 8), FireFox and Chrome.

In the included html example (and fiddle):

selecting "three" by double-clicking:

```
Chrome:
   startNode: textNode containing "Three"
   endNode:   textNode containing "Three"

FireFox/IE:
   startNode: empty textNode (presumably between two and three)
   endNode:   textNode containing "Three"
```

selecting "three" by click and drag:

```
Chrome:
   startNode: textNode containing "Three"
   endNode:   textNode containing "Three"

FireFox/IE:
   startNode: textNode containing "Three"
   endNode:   textNode containing "Three"
```

double-clicking "two" so it, and the space after it, is selected:

```
Chrome:
   startNode: textNode containing "one two"
   endNode:   empty textNode

FireFox/IE:
   startNode: textNode containing "one two"
   endNode:   textNode containing "Three"
```

What I want is for all of the above cases to realize that it's really only one node that was selected. I guess the rule would be to check whether all text in the selection is from the same node. So I tried to traverse it and, lo and behold, nextSibling, children, and whatnot are different for different browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/SvNm8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

     <li>
       <span>one two</span> <span>three</span>
    </li>
    <div id = "x"></div>

</html>

<script> // to show results
document.onmouseup=function(){

    var userSelection = window.getSelection();
    var selected_element = userSelection.anchorNode;
    var last_selected_element = userSelection.focusNode;

    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = selected_element.nodeName + " " + selected_element.nodeValue + " " + last_selected_element.nodeName + " " + last_selected_element.nodeValue ;

    };
</script>
```

Comment: Well, if the space after `two` is selected as well, then it is not only one selected node…

Comment: Try to remove nodes from the selection whose `offset` is zero or at the end.